# How to call several methods of a class instance?

Tags: php, prestashop, instance

I would like to execute two functions of a class, during the same instantiation.
I need two tasks to run at the same time.
See here :

First file : **manage_stock_service.php**

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . "/../../includes/php/initialize.php";
include './../../config/config.inc.php';
include './../../init.php';
include './../ps_emailalerts/MailAlert.php';

class Manage_stock_service extends Initialize   {

    public $resultat;

    public function __construct()   {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->resultat= [];
    }

    public function __destruct()    {
        parent::__destruct();
    }
    
    //Update the stock in database 
    public function manage_stock_supply_order_detail_update()
    {
        $spathSQL_update_stock= $this->GLOBALS_INI["PATH_HOME"] . "files/manage_stock/sql/supply_list/manage_stock_UPDATE_supply_order_update_stock.sql";
        $this->oBdd->getSelectDatas($spathSQL_update_stock, array(
            'id_product' => $old_received['id_product'],
            'id_attribute' => $old_received['id_product_attribute'],
            'quantity' => $diff_received
        ));
    } 

    //Notifies the customer that the product is back in stock.
    public function sendMailToClient()
    {
        $customer_qty = (int) Configuration::get('MA_CUSTOMER_QTY');
        $quantity = $diff_received;

        if ($customer_qty && $quantity > 0) {
            MailAlert::sendCustomerAlert((int) $old_received['id_product'], (int) $old_received['id_product_attribute']);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

And the second : **manage_stock_supply_order_detail_update.php**

```
<?php
require_once "manage_stock_service.php";

class Manage_stock_supply_order_detail_update   {

    public $resultat;

    public function __construct()   {

        $this->resultat = [];

        $this->main();
    }

    function main() {

        $obj_manage_stock_list = new Manage_stock_service();
        $obj_manage_stock_list->manage_stock_supply_order_detail_update();
        $obj_manage_stock_list->sendMailToCustomer();

        $this->resultat = $obj_manage_stock_list->resultat;
        $this->VARS_HTML = $obj_manage_stock_list->VARS_HTML;

        unset($obj_manage_stock_list);
    }
}
?>
```

I was wondering if it was possible to do `$obj_manage_stock_list->sendMailToCustomer();`, and if not what would be the way to execute the function in the `manage_stock_supply_order_detail_update.php` file.

I wanted to execute the `sendMailToCustomer()` function in the `manage_stock_supply_order_detail_update()` function but according to my tests this is impossible.

Does anyone have an idea?
Thanks in advance !

Comment: sendMailToCustomer != sendMailToClient. Typo?

Comment: Is there any reason one of those methods can't call the other one directly? [Side note: You have a class with a name that matches the name of a method in another class. That is often a sign that a coder has not thought carefully about the roles each class performs.]